# How can I change the color of the only active NavHashLink ? activeClassName is selecting both hash Links

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Here is the codesandox link.
https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-ramanujan-ngrzk?file=/src/App.js

```
 <div className="App">
        <NavHashLink className="sticky" to="#tag1" activeClassName="active">
          Scroll to Tag1
        </NavHashLink>
        <NavHashLink className="sticky" to="#tag2" activeClassName="active">
          Scroll to Tag2
        </NavHashLink>

        <p id="tag1" className="bottom100">
          Tag1
        </p>
        <p id="tag2" className="bottom200">
          Tag2
        </p>
      </div>
```

Comment: You're running into version issues. react-router-hash-link states that it covers react-router-dom v5 and your using v6. Change the version of react-router-dom to v5 and it works perfectly https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-albattani-81zwj?file=/src/App.js:52-74

Comment: AFAIK `react-router-hash-link` still hasn't been updated to use the newer `react-router-dom` v6 `Link` component APIs. The issue here is that the path is identical for both links so they are both active at the same time.

Comment: There's an open issue for it https://github.com/rafgraph/react-router-hash-link/issues/92 with v6.

Comment: Is there any other way round for getting the same functionality?

Comment: You could possibly run the fork found in the link Rolando linked in their comment. Or you could fork `react-router-has-link` and fix it yourself (and open PR back to project). Or wait for them to hopefully update. Or you can roll back to RRDv5 where it is all still compatible.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**EDITED**

you can look at how I've done it

https://codesandbox.io/embed/loving-dust-yejsv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: That's the library OP is using.

Comment: Sorry, I don't notice that at the beginning.
I just edited the answer to match his needs.

Thank you